# How to combine 2 foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need to combine the arrays and get separate values but foreach value combine each array.

Is possible ?

This is my starting:

```
$colors = array('foo' => 'bar', 'bar' => 'foo');
$urls = array('url' => 'url.html', 'url' => 'url2.html');

foreach ($colors as $color) {
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo '<div class="'.$color.'"><a href="'.$url.'>'.$color.'</a>';
}
}
```

This is my source with colors and url and the construction is in array data and i want to echo it separately:

```
 $colors = array(5) { [555]=> 
      string(6) "Color1"
      [23]=>
      string(6) "Color2"
      [564]=>
      string(6) "Color2"
      [585]=>
      string(6) "Color2"
      [879]=>
      string(6) "Color3"
    }

   $urls = array(5) {
        [2327]=>
          array(11) {
            ["path"]=>
            string(66) "/home/root/dev/file.png"
          }
        [2328]=>
       array(11) {
            ["path"]=>
            string(66) "/home/root/dev/file.png"
          }
        [2329]=>
        array(11) {
            ["path"]=>
            string(66) "/home/root/dev/file.png"
          }
        [2330]=>
        array(11) {
            ["path"]=>
            string(66) "/home/root/dev/file.png"
          }
        [2331]=>
        array(11) {
            ["path"]=>
            string(66) "/home/root/dev/file.png"
          }
      }
```

Comment: Seems legit. If this isn't working please show us the expected output

Comment: `$urls` only has one value, `url2.html`

Comment: I created an example, maybe i miss the second url. i have updated the question with more accurate details.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the key "url" of each $urls to the key corresponding to the color.
Then in your first foreach loop, do this :

```
foreach ($colors as $key => $color) {
    echo '<div class="'.$color.'"><a href="'.$urls[$key].'>'.$color.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: I said that you have to change the keys ;)